# Shouldn't [hogwarts-legacy] be renamed to [harry-potter-hogwarts-legacy] and/or a synonym be created?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-rename-request

As stated in the title: Shouldn't [hogwarts-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts-legacy) be renamed to [harry-potter-hogwarts-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-hogwarts-legacy) or do we consider it a separate game in the same universe, but not a "true" Harry Potter game, since the character is not featured in the game?

Answer (score 13):

We title our tags based on the game's official name. The official name of the game is "Hogwarts Legacy", without the Harry Potter specification, so we don't mention Harry Potter in the title either. Keep in mind that Hogwarts Legacy is a story set almost 200 years before the events in the original series, and apart from the usual easter eggs in prequels like ancestors of original characters or long-lived/immortal characters making an appearance, The Boy Who Lived has very little to do with this game. In fact, due to the controversial views held by the original author of the book series, the game has actually taken steps to specify that the only connection is that it takes place in the same fictional world and that she does not have any creative input into the game.